# Remove text that is bold in content with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code below to output content from a category, but the content has bold tags which in turn makes my entire sold bold. What would be easiest way to remove the bold text in my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am using this to learn.

```
<p><?php $content = get_the_content();  
                if (mb_strlen($content) > 700) {
                $content = mb_substr($content, 0, 700);
                // make sure it ends in a word by chomping at last space
                $content = mb_substr($content, 0, mb_strrpos($content, " ")).'...<br /><span class="landing_latest_articles_read_more"><a href="" title="">Read More</a></span>';
                }
                echo $content; ?></p>
```

Comment: are there any other tags in the content that you don't want to remove?

Comment: you can also easily take off trailing spaces with `trim($content)`

Comment: @JMC i am talking about bold letters, not spaces. pls read OP

Comment: misread your comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

or this might work

```
$string = preg_replace("/<b>|</b>/", "", $string);
```

Here is a function like strip_tags, only it removes only the tags (with attributes) specified:

```
<?php
function strip_only($str, $tags) {
    if(!is_array($tags)) {
        $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags)) : array($tags));
        if(end($tags) == '') array_pop($tags);
    }
    foreach($tags as $tag) $str = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $str);
    return $str;
}
?>
```

so you will use it like this

```
<p><?php $content = get_the_content();  
                if (mb_strlen($content) > 700) {
                $content = mb_substr($content, 0, 700);
                // make sure it ends in a word by chomping at last space
                $content = mb_substr($content, 0, mb_strrpos($content, " ")).'...<br /><span class="landing_latest_articles_read_more"><a href="" title="">Read More</a></span>';
$content =  strip_only($content, '<b>');   //you want to remove <b> tag            
}
                echo $content; ?></p>
```

This is working. [i tried it here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/i0a6x6).

Comment: that regexp will return an error for sure, you must escape the delimiters... also, why use regexp if you can use `str_replace(array('<b>','</b>','<strong>','</strong>'),'', $string);`

Comment: i am new to PHP. can you show me how that code would work within the code loop i have already?

Comment: seems when i put it in i get this error (unexpected '}' ) steming from the `$content = strip_only($content, '<b>')`

Comment: @Holler: hope you did not miss the ";" in the line $content =  strip_only($content, '<b>'); Do add it then this error wont come.i have changed it now.u do the same.

Comment: figured as much. now i have both the function and your code, but the bold is not being removed :(

Comment: ok.then probably there are other tags like <strong> that might be changing the output format?can you check that somehow?

Comment: ah yes, instead of them using `<b>`they used `<strong>`, so i replaced that in the code and it works perfectly ty.

Comment: how would i remove all html in the content?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to remove bold tags:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<[\/]?b>/i', '', $content);
                            ^
```

Though you'd have to be sure that it is only `<b>` tags making things bold and not font tags.